# What would the proper MVVM architecture be for a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am making an app for iPad using RXSwift and MVVM.

I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView and a ViewModel which acts as the dataSource and the delegate for the collectionView.

Part of the collection cells' functionality is that when a button is tapped to present a popover. Now with the newer popover functionality in iOS 9 (possibly earlier) you need to present the view normally within the view controller, and modify the popoverPresentationController.

Now, as far as i'm aware you are not able to present a UIViewController from a UICollectionViewCell. Makes sense.

But the only way i thought to do this would be to have a delegate that points to the ViewController.

Looking at the class diagram (attached), the viewModel would have to set the delegate upon cell dequeue. To do that the ViewModel would have to know what ViewController to set as the delegate which i'm fairly sure goes against the point of the viewModel. According to MVVM (for iOS) the view model should not know about the view controller. The view controller can know about the view model.

And so my question is what would be the best way to do this following MVVM? If it requires moving the dataSource/Delegate to a different class i'm all for it.

[image: UML Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

I think view model shouldn't be aware of the button being tapped at all. Handling touch events belongs the view layer, as well as presenting the popover.

This also indicates that your view model shouldn't probably be a `UICollectionViewDataSource`. So it is coupled with `RootCollectionViewCell`, which is a view. Unfortunately, this coupling is hard to avoid because Apple designed `UICollectionViewDataSource` this way. You can either extract a separate class as the data source, or leave the data source methods in the view controller (which belongs to the view layer in MVVM on iOS).

Using RxCocoa, you can even avoid implementing `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods at all. Take a look at `UICollectionView+Rx` extensions. There is also an [example in RxSwift repository](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/WikipediaImageSearch/Views/WikipediaSearchCell.swift) (table view cell containing a collection view).

For passing the button taps to the view controller, you can use `rx_tap` Observable and expose it in the cell's interface. Then you can subscribe to the resulting `Observable` in the view controller (or in the separate data source class):

```
//in the cell class
var buttonTapped : ControlEvent<Void> {
    return button.rx_tap
}

//in the data source 
cell.buttonTapped.subscribeNext {
  //show the popover
}.addDisposableTo(cell.disposeBag)
```

As described in [this answer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/437), you should avoid subscribing many times to the same Observable when the cell is reused. That's why `cell.disposeBag` is used in the code above. You should also re-create cell's `disposeBag` in its `prepareForReuse` method:

```
class RootCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var disposeBagCell:DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

    ...

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        disposeBagCell = DisposeBag()
    }

}
```